# Try and Catch run time problems when creating an Object

Tags: c#

I created a class called `Customer`, it has about four fields. I have all getters and setters correctly.

I instantiated an object from `welcomeForm`.

When I click a `Save` button, I run this:

```
 private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
        try
        {
            if (isValidData())
            {
                newCustomer.CustomerName = customerNameTxtBox.Text;
                newCustomer.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt64(customerIdTxtBox.Text);

                newCustomer.CustomerCheckInAmmount = Convert.ToDouble(checkAmountTxtBox.Text);

                double feeTotal = (newCustomer.CustomerCheckInAmmount * (newCustomer.CheckFeeAmmount));

                newCustomer.CustomerCheckOutAmmount = newCustomer.CustomerCheckInAmmount - feeTotal;

                feeTotal = (feeTotal + (newCustomer.CustomerCheckOutAmmount - (int)newCustomer.CustomerCheckOutAmmount));

                totalFeeTxtBox.Text = feeTotal.ToString("c");
                checkTotalTxtBox.Text = newCustomer.CustomerCheckOutAmmount.ToString("c");
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Processor Usage" + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" +
                ex.StackTrace, " Exceptions");
        }
    }

    public bool isValidData()
    {
        return
            IsPresent(customerNameTxtBox, "Customer Name") &&
            IsDouble(checkAmountTxtBox, " Check In") &&
            IsPresent(customerIdTxtBox, "Customer Phone");
    }

    public bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " is a required field.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsDouble(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToDouble(textBox.Text);
            return true;

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " Must be decimal value.", "Entry Error.");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the `Customer` Class

```
 class Customer
{
    private string customerName;
    private Int64 customerID;
    private double customerCheckInAmmount;
    private const double checkFeeAmmount= 3/100;
    private double customerCheckOutAmmount;

    public Customer() { }

    public Customer(string cName, Int64 cID, double checkInCustomer,double checkOutCustomer)
    {
        this.customerName = cName;
        this.customerID = cID;
        this.customerCheckInAmmount = checkInCustomer;
        this.customerCheckOutAmmount = checkOutCustomer;
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return customerName;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!(customerName.Equals("")))
            {
                customerName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Int64 CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return customerID;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!(customerID <= 0))
            {
                customerID = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public double CustomerCheckInAmmount
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomerCheckInAmmount;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!(customerCheckInAmmount <=0.0))
            {
                customerCheckInAmmount = value;
            }
        }

    }

    public double CustomerCheckOutAmmount
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomerCheckOutAmmount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!(customerCheckOutAmmount <= 0.0))
            {
                customerCheckOutAmmount = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public double CheckFeeAmmount
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckFeeAmmount;
        }

    }
    public string getDisplayString(string sep)
    {
        return (customerName +
            sep + customerID +
            sep + customerCheckInAmmount +
            sep + checkFeeAmmount +
            sep + customerCheckOutAmmount);
    }
}
```

}

When I build, I do not get any problems, I do get problems however, when I run. I get this error

> Processor UsageObject reference not set to an instance of an Object.

**on my project at school, I created an object the same way and did not get an error.

Any suggestions would be good. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Which line is that I dont see why customer object would be null?

Comment: this means that you try to address an object that has not been set. Try checking each object and make sure it is a valid object before you address it.

Comment: In addition to the fact that you posted code that doesn't compile (the catch for your try catch is nested in the wrong brace), you haven't included enough code for us to tell you what the problem is. Assuming the getters/setters are valid and that the two text boxes actually exist on the form you're likely running into trouble inside of isValidDate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
public string CustomerName
{
    get
    {
        return customerName;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!(customerName.Equals("")))
        {
            customerName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're calling `Customer newCustomer = new Customer();` you are not initializing the `customerName` string. So when `newCustomer.CustomerName = customerNameTxtBox.Text;` is called it's calling `if(!(customerName.Equals("")))`. At this point you haven't given a value to `customerName` and `customerName` is null. When you try to call equals on it it is throwing a null reference. I recommending changing `if(!(customerName.Equals("")))` to `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName))`.